# Angular + Requirejs - Loading in the wrong order

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asynchronous, requirejs

I'm trying to have angular and jquery loaded with requirejs.  The best I can do is that 50% of the time everything loads correctly, the other half I get the error `No Module: mainApp`

I'm assuming this is breaking half the time based on the speed on which requirejs is asynchronously loading the scripts.

When it works, I see the "Hello World" test (although I do see {{text}} flash before it is replaced, but I've been reading how to fix that here).  The rest of the time I get the error and {{text}} just stays on the screen.

[Github Repo](https://github.com/nick-brown/broken-require)

`Tree:`

```
index.html
- js
    - libs
        require.js
    - modules
        mainApp.js
    main.js
```

---

`main.js`

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    'jQuery': '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min',
    'angular': '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular',
  },
  shim: {
    'angular' : {'exports' : 'angular'},
    'jQuery': {'exports' : 'jQuery'}
  }
});

require(['jQuery', 'angular', 'modules/mainApp'] , function ($, angular, mainApp) {
  $(function () { // using jQuery because it will run this even if DOM load already      happened
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['mainApp']);
  });
});
```

---

`modules/mainApp.js`

```
define(['angular'], function (angular) {
  return angular.module('mainApp' , []).controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
      $scope.text = 'Hello World';
  }]);
});
```

---

`Relevant index.html`

```
<head>
    <script src="js/libs/require.js" data-main="js/main"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="mainApp">
        <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
            {{text}}
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [domReady](https://github.com/requirejs/domReady/blob/master/domReady.js) (**UPDATED**) to make sure that the DOM is fully loaded, i.e. all JS files are there, before bootstrapping your application.

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: '/path/to/jquery',
        angular: 'path/to/angular',
        domReady: '/path/tp/domReady'
    }, shim: {
        angular: {
            exports: 'angular'
        },  
    }   
});
define(['jquery', 'angular', 'modules/mainApp'], 
    function($, angular, 'mainApp') {
        // tell angular to wait until the DOM is ready
        // before bootstrapping the application
        require(['domReady'], function() {
            angular.bootstrap(document, ['mainApp']);
        }); 
});
```

See [the RequireJS official documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#pageload) for more information on this gotcha:

> It is possible when using RequireJS to load scripts quickly enough
>   that they complete before the DOM is ready. Any work that tries to
>   interact with the DOM should wait for the DOM to be ready.

The trick is found on [this](http://limsomnia.blogspot.com/2013/10/it-6-few-tricks-with-angularjs.html) blog post.

**EDIT** If you follow the blog post's advice, please use this domReady script instead of the one I previously posted: https://github.com/requirejs/domReady/blob/master/domReady.js.

Comment: Didn't seem to make any difference.  I even tried to match the blog post's example syntax as exactly as possible.  

Here's the project with your recommended changes: `https://github.com/nick-brown/broken-require/tree/domReady/`

Comment: Note that according [the official documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#pageload) you don't use `domready` like this; you either wrap code in `domready()` call or require it using plugin syntax, i.e. `'domReady!'`. No idea if this is enough to fix OP's problem, though.

Comment: @Nick Brown The blog post uses a different domReady script, hence the differences in syntax. I wrote that post but forgot which script was used. Don't use the one that the official documentation suggested. I've submitted a pull request for your review.

Comment: But why would you use domReady when you could use jQuery .ready() to bootstrap when the DOM is loaded?

Answer (score 2):

Add Jquery as a dependency for Angular in the shim.

```
require.config({
      paths: {
        'jQuery': '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min',
        'angular': '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular',
      },
      shim: {
        'angular' : {'exports' : 'angular', deps: ['jQuery']},
        'jQuery': {'exports' : 'jQuery'}
      }
});
```

Comment: Did not change anything, unfortunately.

Comment: Seems to work when you add https:// to your CDN's
You will still need to bootstrap your app.
angular.bootstrap(document, ["app"]);
But this should get you passed the loading issue.

Comment: Strange, still doesn't work for me but I'm going to give it a try when I get home and on a different connection.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a late response but as Dustin Blake said, you can also use jQuery `.ready()` instead of including another module like `domReady`.

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: '/path/to/jquery',
        angular: 'path/to/angular'
    }, shim: {
        angular: {
            exports: 'angular'
        },  
    }   
});

require(['jquery'], function($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // I like it this way instead of including 
        // everything in the parent function so it's easier to read
        require(['angular', "modules/mainApp"], function(){
         angular.bootstrap(document, ['mainApp']);
        })
    })
});
```